# Application not Installed in Micromax A110 ICS

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have made an app, which works fine in Emulator, but now i am trying to install unsigned apk in my device [Micromax A110 ICS], but whenever i click on install getting message :- Application not installed, why?

Manifest looks like this:-

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS">
    </uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS">
    </uses-permission><uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001">
     </uses-feature><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false">
     </uses-feature><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false">
     </uses-feature><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="true">
     </uses-feature><uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16">
    </uses-sdk><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    </uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK">
    </uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
    </uses-permission><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION">
    </uses-permission>
```

Comment: Have you tick unknow source in setting in device ?

Comment: yes chirag i have ticked

Comment: any message while installing

Comment: @raju Application not Installed

Comment: try with android:required="false" in faketouch permission

Comment: @chiragRaval i will try then let you know

Comment: @ChiragRaval still not buddy

Comment: try to remove this <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001">

Comment: @chiragRaval anything else you think i need to remove or add in permissions please help

Comment: That device does not fulfill one or more of these hardware requirements.

Comment: @ChiragRaval not working

Comment: @Singularity any idea please..what are the changes required

Comment: @ChiragRaval any idea buddy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have enable device for development?

choose Settings >> Applications >> Install from Unknown sources.

Many times unsigned apk creates problem so I recomend you to directly install build by attaching your phone to computer & In Run as android application select your device.

Or 
Make an sign apk & install to your device.

Comment: Please read question and comments first then post your answer.

Comment: @ Chirag Raval Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: @rohitlagu brother i am trying to make signed apk but whenever i click on browse to select location and selecting any location it is not taking always showing blank in place of File Name, and finally not able to create a new keystore, please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/ 


Read from Step 6

Comment: @RWorld thanks for the link i will try that, but i want to ask one more question related to signed apk, this time i just want to generate signed apk to test on my Micromax and can i create another one to launch an app on the market....

Comment: @RWorld finally last question, i have made signed apk but not getting .apk extension everytime why however in unsigned apk getting .apk extension

Comment: u need to write specifically. In saving apk file dialog file type will be *.* u have write  appname.apk

Thanks

Comment: @RWorld thanks again bro for fast reply and i will check that, then let back to you, hopefully with done....